# can we create mobile application for windows mobile using oracle adf mobile

Tags: mobile, oracle-adf

I want to create a mobile application that can access all the oracle E-business suite application. So is it possible to create application for windows mobile using oracle adf mobile

Answer (score 0):

Not with the current version - the current version of ADF Mobile supports iOS and Android devices.

Comment: I have one more question and it is that since we are using java for business logic and it is platform independent so why not for windows mobile. And the rest languages such as Html5, javascript are also platform independent.

Comment: The code that gets generated by JDeveloper gets converted to native code, so Java for Android and C for iOS. And that conversion process still needs to be done for Windows Mobile.